# Greasemonkey without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, greasemonkey

Hey I have got this code that answers questions autimatically via greasemonkey but it only works when I refresh the page. The questions are coming by AJAX so as soon as the page refreshes the whole game does not work otherwise if I keep it this way without refreshing the code does not work on the second third etc. questions.

So my question is is it possible to keep greasemonkey working without refreshing the page constantly ?

```
See:  http://jsfiddle.net/t2AzN/14/
```

Comment: Can you send an ajax request to greasemonkey site and update your html page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t2AzN/14/

Comment: yes it is,, but you didn't posted enough code,, you didn't posted that page that has questions coming by AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

If you put the code that answers the question into a function called `answerQuestions`, then something like this might work for you (adapted from the example linked above):

```
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('question-container');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  answerQuestions();    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks you it worked... I have an other question. Can you help me? How can i auto click query button or li tag ?

Comment: You need to trigger a click event on the element you want.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events for how to do it the standard way.  Frameworks like jQuery have methods that make this kind of thing much more simple.